# Reorganize dictionary order by values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an app that receives an Json file from my webserver and I convert to NSDictionary as you can see below:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError]
```

The structure of my dictionary is as follows:

```
[0] => { "name" = "josh", meters = "8"  }
[1] => { "name" = "lina", meters = "10"  }
[2] => { "name" = "pall", meters = "21"  }
```

You can see that data is already organized by the key `meters`, unfortunately my webserver not give the possibility to maintain an open connection, in this case, the new records will come through the **APNS (push notification)**

Assuming that comes the following record by notification:

```
{"name" = "oli", meters = "12"}
```

I insert it in my dictionary, but once that's done, how can I rearrange my array and order by meters?

Comment: try to convert the dic into an array, and use NSSortDescriptor and sort it and  convert the array back to dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no order inherent in the dictionary.  That you see an ordering in the initial set is accidental.

Arrays have ordering, and you can get an array from a dictionary by sending it `allKeys` or `allValues`.

Using this fact to organize the dictionary, you might try something like this:

```
NSArray *orderedPairs = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (id key in [someDictionary allKeys]) {
    [orderedPairs addObject:@[key, someDictionary[key]]];
}

[orderedPairs sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray *a, NSArray *b) {
    // return [a[0] compare:b[0]];  // to sort by key 
    return [a[1] compare:b[1]];  // to sort by value 
}];
```

Note that this will result in an array -- not a dictionary -- but one that is ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary doesn't have order. it's simply key-value pair. you can fetch value for particular key so doesn't require sorting or ordering like array.